# Not getting event data from windows 10 in rsyslog, using NXLog-CE as log forwarding agent

Tags: window, windows-installer, event-log, rsyslog, nxlog

I have generated an event by installing an msi from the web using `msiexec` command.

[msiexec command screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H1Su.png)

And when i checked the event viewer, there was a event generated, with the url inside event data.

[event-viewer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KxQZ.png)

My NXLog config for this windows-10 system is as follows:

```
Panic Soft
#NoFreeOnExit TRUE

define ROOT     C:\Program Files\nxlog
define CERTDIR  %ROOT%\cert
define CONFDIR  %ROOT%\conf\nxlog.d
define LOGDIR   %ROOT%\data

include %CONFDIR%\\*.conf
define LOGFILE  %LOGDIR%\nxlog.log
LogFile %LOGFILE%

Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
CacheDir  %ROOT%\data
Pidfile   %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
SpoolDir  %ROOT%\data

<Extension _syslog>
    Module      xm_syslog
</Extension>

<Extension json>
    Module xm_json
</Extension>

<Extension _charconv>
    Module      xm_charconv
    AutodetectCharsets iso8859-2, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32
</Extension>

<Extension _exec>
    Module      xm_exec
</Extension>

<Extension _fileop>
    Module      xm_fileop

    # Check the size of our log file hourly, rotate if larger than 5MB
    <Schedule>
        Every   1 hour
        Exec    if (file_exists('%LOGFILE%') and \
                   (file_size('%LOGFILE%') >= 5M)) \
                    file_cycle('%LOGFILE%', 8);
    </Schedule>

    # Rotate our log file every week on Sunday at midnight
    <Schedule>
        When    @weekly
        Exec    if file_exists('%LOGFILE%') file_cycle('%LOGFILE%', 8);
    </Schedule>
</Extension>

# Snare compatible example configuration
# Collecting event log
<Input in>
     Module      im_msvistalog
</Input>
# 
# Converting events to Snare format and sending them out over TCP syslog
<Output out>
    Module  om_tcp
    Host    <rsyslog-ip>
    Port    514
    Exec    $raw_event = " namanWindowVm " + to_json();
</Output>
# 
# Connect input 'in' to output 'out'
<Route 1>
     Path        in => out
</Route>
```

in place of rsyslog-ip, i have put the ip of rsyslog server.

I am not getting any log in rsyslog server, which has this url('https://www.exemsi').

[rsyslog server command screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVv1R.png)

the configuration of rsyslog is as follows:

```
# /etc/rsyslog.conf configuration file for rsyslog
#
# For more information install rsyslog-doc and see
# /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/configuration/index.html
#
# Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

#module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
#module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")

# provides kernel logging support and enable non-kernel klog messages
#module(load="imklog" permitnonkernelfacility="on")

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


*.* /var/log/incoming-logs.log
```

PS: i am using a windows-10 vm inside a ubuntu-22.04 system.

I have tried to search via command line in rsyslog server, but i am not getting any log having 'https://www'. I want to have this url in the logs.